# Drachtio server not connecting with nodejs application

Tags: node.js

I have downloaded the docker image of drachtio server and also run that image with command "docker run imageName".My docker image is running fine.But my nodejs application is not connecting with drachtio server can someone please guide me what i am missing.I am using drachtio-srf npm package in nodejs application.

Error coming:-Error: connect ECONNREFUSED 127.0.0.1:9022

```
     This is my "docker run imageName" command output:-
     2019-10-22 05:37:39.327360 Starting drachtio version v0.8.3-4- 
     g8fe175fb0
     2019-10-22 05:37:39.327486 Logging threshold:                     
     5
     2019-10-22 05:37:39.327532 DrachtioController::run: Main thread 
     id: 139951985551168
     2019-10-22 05:37:39.327572 DrachtioController::run: no sip 
     contacts provided, will listen on 5060 for udp and tcp 
     2019-10-22 05:37:39.329675 DrachtioController::run listening for 
     applications on tcp port 9022 and tls port 0
     2019-10-22 05:37:39.331442 ClientController::ClientController 
     done setting tls options: 


const Srf = require('drachtio-srf');
const srf = new Srf();
srf.connect({ host: '127.0.0.1', port: 9022, secret: 'cymru' })
srf.on('connect', (err, hp) => {
if (err) console.log("errr",err);
console.log(`connected to server listening on ${hp}`);
});
```

Comment: I encounter the same issue, have you fixed it?

Answer (score 0):

I have had this happen before. Likely it is because the 9022 port on the docker image is not exposed to the host. Try running your docker with `-p 127.0.0.1:9022:9022/tcp` or any other port you'd prefer to connect on.